# Programmatically change WooCommerce subscriptions payment method

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions, payment-method

while adding a new card , if user click particular card to make it "as default" all subscriptions from other cards should be moved to selected card. All of my logic is working fine.

`$new_default_card` : This variable has new card data (object)
`$subscription` : This variable has subscription data (object)

I want to update the payment method from other cards to new one.

`set_payment_method` : This method isn't updating anything rather it remove subscriptions from other cards.

```
// Get the new default payment method details
$new_default_card = WC_Payment_Tokens::get($token_id);

$payment_method = WC_Payment_Tokens::get_customer_tokens(get_current_user_id());

$user_id = get_current_user_id(); // Get the current user ID

// Query subscriptions using WC_Subscriptions function
$args = array(
    'subscriptions_per_page' => -1, // Get all subscriptions
    'status' => array( 'active', 'on-hold', 'pending', 'cancelled', 'switched', 'expired' ), // 
    'customer_id' => $user_id, // Filter by customer ID
);

$subscription = wcs_get_subscriptions( $args );

$subscription->set_payment_method($payment_method->get_data()['token']);

$subscription->save();
```

Comment: Thank you for editing @LoicTheAztec , new here  , every help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As `wcs_get_subscriptions( $args );` is not a WC_Subscription object but an array of WC_Subscription objects, so the method `set_payment_method()` can't be applied to a non WC_Subscription object and should throw an error…

From your code, try to replace:

```php
$subscription = wcs_get_subscriptions( $args );

$subscription->set_payment_method($payment_method->get_data()['token']);

$subscription->save();
```

with the following:

```php
// Loop through customer subscriptions
foreach( wcs_get_subscriptions( $args ) as $subscription ) {
    $subscription->set_payment_method($payment_method->get_data()['token']);
    $subscription->save();
}
```

It should better work…

Comment: You are right , I did that , but set_payment_method still removing the subscriptions from other cards and not assigning them to a selected one. The argument on set_payment_method is supposed to be token right ? not id or something else?

Comment: *"…from other **cards**"* doesn't mean anything to me… Try to reword your question related to that. The problem surely comes from your implementation: the method `set_payment_method()` requires a valid payment method slug (which is the payment ID). I am not sure that you can change of payment method for a subscription, as the payment is handle by the payment gateway that has been **approved by the customer** where customer has provided its credit card details.